# How do I insert API pagination using Python 3 & requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pagination, python-requests

I make an API call using requests, and get a JSON response back. The API limit is 20 results per page. I can access the first page without a problem, however I cannot figure out how to include pagination in the query. In the JSON response, at the bottom of the page, it gives me the following information.

```
 },
"_links":{
  "first":{
    "href":"https://search-lastSale?date=20190723-20190823&page=0&size=20
  },
  "last":{
    "href":"https://search-lastSale?date=20190723-20190823&page=4&size=20
  },
  "next":{
    "href":"https://search-lastSale?date=20190723-20190823&page=1&size=20
  },
  "self":{
    "href":"https://search-lastSale?date=20190723-20190823&page=0&size=20
  }
},
"page":{
  "number":0,
  "size":20,
  "totalElements":77,
  "totalPages":4
}
```

I've read the docs at https://2.python-requests.org//en/latest/user/advanced/#link-headers and various other articles and posts, but everything seems very specific to people's own APIs.

I've taken my code back to just a single URL request, and old auth token just so I can get a grasp of it, then rescale up to my existing project. The code below:

```
url = "https://search-api.corelogic.asia/search/au/property/postcode/401249/lastSale"

querystring = {"page":"0","size":"20","date":"20190723-20190823"}

headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/JSON",
    'Authorization': "My Token"}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

As far as I can tell from the docs and reading, what I should be doing is either:

1. Get a JSON response back that finds the page count, and then send a new request with a custom list of URLs that reference that count somehow, i.e.

   ```
   if 'totalPages = [4]
       https:www.search/page0
       https:www.search/page1
       https:www.search/page2
       https:www.search/page3
       https:www.search/page4
   ```

   loop through each URL and append the JSON file; or
2. Utilise the 'next' page in the JSON response to grab the next url, until there is no 'next' page in the JSON file, i.e.

   ```
   While json.response = ['next']
       keep getting data
       append to open json file
   ```

Both methods make sense, however I cannot see where this pagination would exist in my code.

Comment: Yes, you keep calling the "next" link. It's unclear what you mean by "where".

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe - thanks for the question edit, I guess i didn't realize how much frustration came out of the keyboard!. In relation to "where" - I cannot seem to find anyway of adding code that will work. For example: at the moment im trying to work with the following code 

while response.links["next"] != response.links["last"]:
    r = requests.get(r.links["next"], headers=headers, params=querystring)
    raw = r.json()
    for i in raw:
        results.append(i)
as a snippet - and im getting the below error 


KeyError: 'next'

Comment: Then put a [mcve] of that in the question. But the error message is clear: at a certain point, there *isn't* a "next" link.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, in the response you receive there is the `_links` `dict`, you can use the `href` inside `next` to get next page.

Or you can try to manually generate those urls:

```
>>> def paged_url(page: int=0, size=20) -> str:
...     return ("https://search-lastSale?date=20190723-20190823&"
...             f"page={page}&size={size}")
... 
>>> paged_url(1)
'https://search-lastSale?date=20190723-20190823&page=1&size=20'
>>> paged_url(2)
'https://search-lastSale?date=20190723-20190823&page=2&size=20'
>>> paged_url(3, 10)
'https://search-lastSale?date=20190723-20190823&page=3&size=10'
```

Those URLs contain the next page you should fetch.